# ExecutorLostFailure during reading 2-3M length of array field on a single row

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Im using apache-spark, scala, and I run my job on yarn-cluster.

Input file contains 3gb of data, file format is avro-parquet, and the schema contains ff fields:

```
{
     name: String,
     value: Array[String]
}
```

The thing is, my spark job runs smoothly from the start, then skew at the last partition (the array length of 'value' field is approx 2M+), then I got the ExecutorLostFailure error. My job keeps trying but at the end still fails.

This is my job configure so far. I tried increasing my executor memory from 1gb to 4gb but i still got the error:

```
--driver-memory 8192m 
--executor-cores 1 
--executor-memory 4096m 
--num-executors 128 
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 
--conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2048
```

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed this by updating ff configurations:

```
--executor-memory 5G 
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1250
```

I also add these configurations since I don't cache/persist any RDDs and to have more space for my user objects:

```
--conf spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.01 
--conf spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.1
```

But if there are other solutions your answers is very much welcome.